# Error: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have created an Excel add-in using the Office JS library. My add-in works fine with Office 365 but when try to run the same add-in with Office 2019 or 2016 it shows a blank screen only and throws **error** : ***Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page***.

[image]

In some GitHub issues, they are saying that **Internet Explorer 11** doesn't understand **ES6**. I have tried converting all **arrow functions to normal functions** and added **target as ES6 in tsconfig** also.

Please give any solution for how to run the add-in with all the Office versions.

Comment: How does your code look like for the task pane? Have you tried creating a new sample add-in with a task pane and run it there? Does it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Office Add-in cannot successfully call any Office JavaScript APIs until the library has been loaded. [Initialize your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in) article describes the two ways your code can ensure that the library has been loaded:

- Initialize with `Office.onReady()`.
- Initialize with `Office.initialize`.

Make sure you have defined any of them in your add-in.

Comment: I have defined both of them but it's not working.

Comment: There is no need to define both of them. Only one of them should be used in the code.

Comment: Yes, I just tried the all scenarios. Currently, I am only using Office.onReady() as below Office.onReady(() => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
});

Comment: It's working on office 365 but with office 2016 and 2019 not working

Comment: I suppose you are using some engines for the task pane like React or Angular and earlier versions of the web browser can't render it, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am using React and the earlier version of the web browsers (IE 11) can't render it. Can you suggest to me whether it is possible or not to render the task pane on an old browser with React?

Comment: Does it work if you try a standalone application with your app in that browser version?

Comment: No it's working on IE11 but working fine on the Edge.

Comment: So, the problem is with your application, not related to Office web add-ins, correct?